# How to fix strange behavior of vertexes? (picture)

Tags: mesh, rigging, vertices

I cant understand the reason why this two vertexes move like if they are linked.
If I move one, the other moves too in a different direction, if I change the weight of one, weight of the other changes to opposite.
Please, someone, help to fix this!
[image]

Comment: check symmetry options like X mirror of weight paint (in T panel, options tab)

Comment: X mirror is off

Comment: Could you upload .blend? http://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Did I attachedd it to my post?

Comment: nope, just copy/paste the link

Comment: @Bithur
I am new here. How to upload files?

Comment: go : http://pasteall.org/blend/ click browse and select your file, click upload then copy the link. Then come back here, edit your question or add a comment and paste your link.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FiPCG.pngfile:///home/lobzik/%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%91%D0%9E%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%AF/MODELS%20&%20RENDERS/%D0%A6%D0%95%D0%9D%D0%A2%D0%A0%20%D0%9E%D0%9A%D0%95%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%9E%D0%93%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%A4%D0%98%D0%98/problem.blend

Comment: @Bithur I am uploading it now

Comment: Here is it
http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34929

Answer (score 2):

Your vertices are weighted on bad bones.
[image]
The selected vertex should have 1 for Bone1.035 and nothing else. This can be seen in Edit mode in the N panel. From there you can change the weight values (in this case, 1 for Bone1.035 and remove with X bone3.044).
The other vertex needs to have only bone3.044.
Once this is done, place your vertices where they should be and they'll do what you expect.

You're life would be easier with better bones names (Something like Arm1.bone1, arm1.bone2, Arm2.bone1 ...)

Comment: This feature in N-panel is very handy! Will keep in mind. Agree about names.
But after removing extensive bones in N-panel for both vertexes the problem is still here. When I move one of them the other keeps moving to where it wants.

Comment: Oh, here is it!
Now I turned the mirror off and everirhing became OK :)
Thank you very much! You are cool specialist, Bithur!

Comment: glad to help, have fun :)